# How to parse the inner instructions of the transaction's instruction?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, instructions, idl

**Its parsing only transaction instructions, but not inner.**

```
import { PublicKey, Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { SolanaParser } from "@debridge-finance/solana-transaction-parser";
import { RaydiumIDL } from "./idl/raydium.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const rpcConnection = new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_RPC_ENDPOINT_2);

const txParser = new SolanaParser([{ idl: RaydiumIDL, programId: "CAMMCzo5YL8w4VFF8KVHrK22GGUsp5VTaW7grrKgrWqK" }]);

const parsed = await txParser.parseTransaction(
    rpcConnection,
    "3bSaEg71kkWDPtG94mn9bY8k2D7mABaqrQqL4F5JvzAEwukjqqwkjGhHBCb9fS5wVe1AG1J8i76ScKTZ59VGgJzt",
    false,
);

console.log(parsed);

const tokenSwapIx = parsed?.find((pix) => pix.name === "swap");

console.log(tokenSwapIx);
```

**swap parsing output:**

```
{
  name: 'swap',
  accounts: [
    {
      name: 'payer',
      isSigner: true,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(9vu7XMz8Brmfm4mT1T2E1YzemsUCwQEzeM3DrocPBxWc)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'ammConfig',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(HfERMT5DRA6C1TAqecrJQFpmkf3wsWTMncqnj3RDg5aw)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'poolState',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(2QdhepnKRTLjjSqPL1PtKNwqrUkoLee5Gqs8bvZhRdMv)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'inputTokenAccount',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(BkJFS1HF6JgrsB1VXdTVMsZ7R6WCKqokCqhUZqarPPVZ)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'outputTokenAccount',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(7exzsvjn46jweUp1uerS3SYMmHUdQcBgrQi2MHMv5fJV)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'inputVault',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(4d35yC7C8zhCDec7JbPptL9SEb4NUddKHxURgmvD8hfo)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'outputVault',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(E2BcoCeJLTa27mAXDA4xwEq3pBUcyH6XXEHYk4KvKYTv)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'observationState',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(4fEjbMXTet3w8qhScPmT6X79ypagRydKLHPqcGsrhcmP)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'tokenProgram',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'tickArray',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(BBG3DNdnJZXSxURzXSYZ7f8tW42EEDzsTt3Wj9AT1BBH)]]
    },
    {
      name: 'Remaining 0',
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
      pubkey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(4zNMSCni6fNg23uvgY8LjrZWYa1f4gnUHMM4u7CLs9FD)]]
    }
  ],
  programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(CAMMCzo5YL8w4VFF8KVHrK22GGUsp5VTaW7grrKgrWqK)] {
    _bn: <BN: a5d5ca9e04cf5db590b714ba2fe32cb159133fc1c192b72257fd07d39cb0401e>
  },
  args: {
    amount: <BN: 16ea5efa4b>,
    otherAmountThreshold: <BN: 0>,
    sqrtPriceLimitX64: <BN: 3d19d07303606e50>,
    isBaseInput: true
  }
}
```

**Example of what I want to get:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head but should be close enough:

for (const inner of tx.meta.innerInstructions) {
for (const i of inner.instructions) {
if (i.parsed.type === "transfer") {
const amount = i.parsed.info.amount
const source = i.parsed.info.source
const destination  = i.parsed.info.destination
const authority = i.parsed.info.authority
}
}
}

you'll also have to handle "transferChecked" in addition to transfer (it has slightly different structure for the amount, it adds an object with the decimals and amount}